# Is there a way to run terratest on terraform codes in azure devops pipelines?

Tags: azure-devops, terraform, azure-pipelines, terraform-provider-azure, terratest

I am a beginner in the terratesting. I have an assignment where I have to perform terratesting for InfraStructure code that I wrote in terraform. I went through the documentation "https://terratest.gruntwork.io/docs/getting-started/introduction/". And so far I am able to perform terratest for Azure in VS code locally. I wanted to do it in Azure DevOps Pipeline. Is there a way to perform these test cases in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> And so far I am able to perform terratest for Azure in VS code
> locally. I wanted to do it in Azure DevOps Pipeline. Is there a way to
> perform these test cases in Azure DevOps pipelines?

Actually we normally test Terraform modules using Terratest in `Azure` instead of `Azure Devops Service`. You can follow [Tutorial:Test Terraform modules in Azure using Terratest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/test-modules-using-terratest) if you're interested in doing that in Azure.

But if you do need some directions about is it possible and how to do that using Azure Devops Pipelines, the answer is yes. And here's one great blog from **Julien Corioland**: [Continuous Integration using Docker and Azure Pipeline](https://blog.jcorioland.io/archives/2019/09/25/terraform-microsoft-azure-ci-docker-azure-pipeline.html). Hope it helps :)

Comment: The first link above is 404'd, sadly.

Comment: I think link was moved somewhere else hence 404 .You can refer here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/terraform/test-modules-using-terratest